# Fortify, how to run sourceanalyzer on a specific folder?

Tags: fortify

I have a project folder with source code and a lot of other folders inside. The structure is something like the following:

My_project:
 node_modules
 src
 dist
 features
 helpers
 folder1
 folder2
 blablabla
 somefiles.js
 etc

I want to run the scan ONLY on folder 'dist'. The '-exclude' is not a good option because there are really a lot of folders and files there. The main idea is that I dont want to see issues with node_modules and other in fortify results. I only want to see what issues are in 'dist'.

Currently, I am running the following commands:

sourceanalyzer -clean
sourceanalyzer -b My_project ./dist/**/*

sourceanalyzer -Xmx8G -Xms4G -Xss24M -64 -logfile my.log -scan ./dist/**/* -f My_project.fpr
and then upload

For some reason I see issues in node_modules in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your translation command is in the right direction, but try this:
sourceanalyzer -b My_project dist/**/*.*
sourceanalyzer -b My_project -Xmx8G -Xms4G -Xss24M -64 -logfile my.log -scan My_project.fpr

You don’t need the directory info in the scan command. Fortify “translates” your code in the first code and then the second command runs the scan against translated code.

Comment: So you recommended to execute below two commands, right?   
sourceanalyzer -b My_project dist/**/
sourceanalyzer -b My_project -Xmx8G -Xms4G -Xss24M -64 -logfile my.log -scan My_project.fpr

What is the meaning of both command. where can i get the details of these command?